# String format using regex in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a String in the format of "20150403" and I want to convert it into the  format of string like "2015-04-03". Is there any way using regular expression and string format in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample

```
val date = """(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})""".r
val date(year, month, day) = "20150402"
println(s"$year-$month-$day") // 2015-04-02
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is slow. For this u need not use regex , u can use string.substring .

```
val today="20150403"
val out=today.substring(0,4)+"-"+today.substring(4,6)+"-"+today.substring(6)
```

Comment: Or `f"${today}%.4s-${today.drop(4)}%.2s-${today.drop(6)}"`